# How to design table structure for Operating Hours

Tags: mysql, sql

Problem #1:

How can the table be designed in MySQL in efficient way to structure

```
1) Store Opening Time, 
2) Break Time and 
3) Closing Time in a day
```

For an instance, On Sunday: Opening Time: 7:00AM, Closing Time: 5:00PM, Break Time Start: 1:00PM, Break Time End: 2:30PM.

Problem #2:

How to define the query to search that table for all Stores that are being Opened/Closed between the given range.
For an instance, If user tries to filter the stores for Opening between 9:00AM and 12:00AM. How can I apply query for this filter since it might be possible the Break Time or Closing Time could be within that timeframe.

```
store_id    day open_time   break_start break_end   close_time
1           mon 7:00AM      1:00PM      2:30PM      5:00PM
1           tue 7:00AM      1:00PM      2:30PM      5:00PM
1           wed 7:00AM      1:00PM      2:30PM      5:00PM
1           thu 7:00AM      1:00PM      2:30PM      5:00PM
1           fri 7:00AM      1:00PM      2:30PM      5:00PM
1           sat Closed
1           sun Closed
```

Something similar to this. If the user uses criteria: Open Time between: 8:00AM to 2:00PM; to search the store then He must be able to see all the stores that are opened during that timeframe. This timeframe must also include with store open_time. That is, based on criteria provided, the store is Open at 7:00AM, 8:00AM and 9:00AM and until 2:PM.

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: Is it a schedule or list of actual openings and closings populated each time the store opens/closes? Anyway, it seems your store has a state (_open_, _closed_, _closed-for-a-break_ maybe as third one if you need it) and it changes in time, so it has beginning and end.

Comment: Its a list of actual_openings and closings including a break duration within the timeframe.

Comment: provide some sample dummy data please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to create three different columns, since you want to query between 
Opening time , closing time or  break time

```
create table store_timing
(
store_id int, -- from store table
Opening_Time datetime,
break_time datetime,
closing_time datetime
)
```

**Query :**

```
select * 
from store_timing 
where Opening_Time<= 'Opening_Time' 
  and closing_time <= 'closing_time'
```

Comment: Sir, I've provided more details on my question. For an instance, If user tries to filter the stores for Opening between 9:00AM and 12:00AM. How can I apply query for this filter since it might be possible the Break Time or Closing Time could be within that timeframe.